# Why is the error message that "You can't create a direct active relationship..."?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Can you help me to understand why did I get such error message when trying to model my table relationships:

*" You can't create a direct active relationship between Company Info and Query 2 because that would introduce ambiguity between table Query 2 and Query. To make this relationship active, deactive or delete one of the relationships between Query 2 and Query first"*

Query and Query 2 are two tables from two different PowerBi datasets that I connected with Azure Monitor Logs. I have created also a Date Table. My purpose is to connect the Date Table and the Company Info Table with both Query tables so that I could filter the data with date and company (industries, areas...). In details, I tried to connect field Date in Date Table with timestamp in both Query Tables, and field Azure Montor Logs in Company Info Table with OrganizationName in both Query Tables.

Can you give me some idea what went wrong and how can I fix this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VitP7.png)

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!